# Can a return statement returning the result of a ternary expression be made to not return for one branch of the ternary?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to write this if statement in ternary operator (shorthand of c# if)? If yes what would it be?

```
   if (condition)
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      int a = 2;
   }
```

Thanx everyone in advance. Thank you very much.

Sorry guys if I confused you. I am trying to use ternary operator in this if else block of the method.

```
public static bool CompareDictionary(this Dictionary<Position, char> 
    dictionary1,
    Dictionary<Position, char> dictionary2, out List<string> wordList)
{
    string str = "";
    wordList = new List<string>();

    foreach (var dic1KeyVal in dictionary1)
    {
        Position d1key = dic1KeyVal.Key;
        char d1Pos = dic1KeyVal.Value;

        bool isFound = false;
        foreach (var dic2KeyVal in dictionary2)
        {
            Position d2key = dic2KeyVal.Key;
            char d2Pos = dic2KeyVal.Value;

            if (d1Pos.Equals(d2Pos) && d1key == d2key)
            {
                isFound = true;
                str = str + d1Pos.ToString();
            }
        }

        if (isFound == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {

            wordList.Add(str);
            str = "";
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: No and because the ternary operator is used to return values and those values must be assigned to a variable. So the return values must return the same type.

Comment: No, that’s not possible. `int a = 2;` in a block by itself also does nothing. Could you edit in a real
 example, please?

Comment: if (isFound == false) { return false; }
else { wordList.Add(str); str = ""; }

Comment: *Why* do you want to use the ternary operator here? IMO it gives you no benefits over how the code is written now.

Answer (score 14):

**Short Answer**

No.

**Long Answer**

First of all this code does not even need an else:

```
if (condition)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
   int a = 2;
}
```

and can be written as:

```
if (condition)
{
   return true;
}

int a = 2;
```

Now for ternary operator: Both conditions in a ternary operator must return the same thing. You cannot return a `bool` in one condition and then assign to a variable in another condition. If you were checking the answer to a question, for example, it would be like this:

```
return answer == 2 ? true : false;
```

Whether the answer is correct or not, we return a `bool`. Or it could be like this:

```
return answer == 2 ? 1: -1;
```

But not like this:

```
return answer == 2 ? true : "wrong"; // will not compile
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The ternary operator just returns one out of two potential values depending on a condition.

What you can do with the ternary operator is, e.g. `int a = condition ? 0 : 2` which would assign the variable `a` value of either 0 or 2 depending on the value of `condition`.

Given a more complete example of what you intend to do someone here could potentially come up with a nicer syntax.